# Passing ng-directive to Leaflet L.popup().setContent()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, leaflet

Thank you for giving my question a look.

**Goal: Pass an Angular directive to the .setContent() method of L.popup()**

**The Problem**:

I need to run $compile on the directive in order for it to enter ng.  But something like

```
.setContent($compile('<new_marker_form></new_marker_form'))
```

yields a

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
```

as I bet the ng is trying to compile before leaflet has actually appeneded any HTML.

Not sure if this is better suited for Stack Overflow.  Please let me know if I ought to move it.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm stuck with the same problem. The answer in this thread couldn't resolve this problem for me.

Comment: Okay I found the problem: $compile('<new_marker_form></new_marker_form>')({})[0] works.

Answer (score 3):

The closing `>` is missing in your example, not sure if it is just a typo in the question.

And you haven't linked the compiled element to any scope, the result of `$compile` is not an element, but a linking function. You have to call the function by passing a scope object that you want the element to bind with (or a least an empty object).

```
var linkFn = $compile('<new_marker_form></new_marker_form>');
var element = linkFn({}); // or pass any scope object, may be $rootScope.$new() if you do not have one.
L.popup().setContent(element[0]); // use element[0] to pass a DOM instead of jQuery/jqLite object.
```

Or a one liner ..

```
L.popup().setContent($compile('<new_marker_form></new_marker_form>')({}));
```

Hope this helps.