# Button click event in a pop up on leaflet.js

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

When I click on a map, a pop up is displayed with a dropdown list and button. When I select a value from the dropdown list and click the button, a marker should be inserted on the map. 
I'm using the following code to include drop down and button:

```
var popup = L.popup()
.setLatLng([51.5, -0.09])
.setContent("<div> <select></select> <button ng-click='addNode()'> Add </button> <button></div")
.openOn(mymap);
```

The `addNode()` is not getting called when the button is clicked. Could anyone please let me know the issue? Also, is there any other way to include div elements other than using `.setContent`? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with leaflet context. I had similar issue when using leaflet.js with Angular2. Use $compile method to get the proper context.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

This post should help you with this:
[Passing ng-directive to Leaflet L.popup().setContent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299128/passing-ng-directive-to-leaflet-l-popup-setcontent)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How should I get the selected value from the dropdown list to button click event?

Comment: I have tried the following and still ng-click is not working. Any thoughts on that?                                                                                                 var str1 = angular.element("<div> <select>" + concatString + "</select> <button ng-click='addNode()'> Add </button> <button> Remove </button> <button> Cancel </button></div>");
var str2 = $compile(str1);
var result = str2($scope);